# Download a file from a page (cookies needed) using post request

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection

I have tested the first step (the login page) and it works. I put all parameters (user, pass, etc) and I can print the result (page with my data). The problem is when I try to download a file from that web. I need the cookies from the first step. In the file that I download I have the message: "Expired session". This is my code:

```
URL login = new URL("..."); 
URL download_page = new URL("..."); 
URL document_link new URL("..."); 


//String for request
String data_post = "username=name&password=1234&other_data=..."; 

//Login page
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)login.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
wr.write(data_post); 
wr.close(); 
conn.connect(); 

//Download page
HttpURLConnection connDownload = (HttpURLConnection)download_page.openConnection(); 
connDownload.connect(); 

//Link to the file 
HttpURLConnection connFile = (HttpURLConnection)document_link.openConnection(); 
connFile.connect(); 

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connFile.getInputStream()); 

File saveFile = new File("myfile.txt"); 
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile)); 
byte[] buf = new byte[256]; 
int n = 0; 
while ((n=in.read(buf))>=0) { 
   out.write(buf, 0, n); 
} 
out.flush(); 
out.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at Apache HttpClient - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the headers for a cookie on the first page before closing the connection? I'd try something like:

`String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");`

Then set the cookie subsequently in the following connections, before executing connect(), using:

`connDownload.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);`

... See if that works ...